# Parse a text file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am stuck with this activity ,I have a txt file like below

```
0112 00000 34 JOB RECOVERY status poll (ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001) ACCEPTED, OWNER
0112 00000 35 JOB RECOVERY status poll (ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001)STARTED , APPL TYPE
0112 00000 36 JOB PROCESS_kafka(ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) ACCEPTED , OWNER
0112 00001 37 JOB PROCESS_kafka (ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) STARTED, APPL_TYPE
0112 00001 38 JOB RECOVERY  status poll(ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001) ENDED OK ,ELAPSED - 0.02 SEC
0112 00003 39 JOB PROCESS (ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) ENDED OK, ELAPSED - 2.28 SEC
```

i need to get elapsed - value for each orderid for each job , i need like if orderid is 2N000, then the elapsed i should get-0.02 sec. like this for each orderid i need to get from the file using shell script.

I need the output like

```
orderid    jobname     ELAPSED
2N000      RECOVERY    0.02
2NOO1      PROCESS     2.28
```

Comment: Please, post the related expected output.
Don't post is as a comment, an image, a table
or a link to an off-site service but use text
and include it to your original question. Also, as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. 
 Thanks

Comment: awk could solve the problem easily. But can you please show what do you have so far? I mean, the script.

Comment: I tried to grep ORDERID filename | awk pattern , same for elapsed also ..but that gives me wrong matching of orerid and elapsed, @kent

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ELAPSED file.txt \
| cut -d' ' -f7,5,14 \
| sed -E 's/(.*) ([^[:space:]]+),/\2 \1/'
```

- `grep` selects just the lines with "ELAPSED";
- `cut` extracts just the columns with orderid, jobname, and elapsed time;
- But they are in the wrong order, so `sed` removes the comma from the orderid and reorders the columns.

If `sed` is not available, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/ELAPSED/{id=$7; sub(",", "", id); print id, $5, $14}' file.txt
```

- On lines containing `ELAPSED`, the seventh value is stored in `id`, comma is removed from it, and the `id`, jobname, and elapsed time are printed.

Comment: sed giving me :no such file or directory

Comment: @Deepak: Do you mean you don't have `sed` installed?

Comment: yes @choroba ..is there any other way

Comment: Do you have `awk` installed? Or `perl`?

Comment: i have awk installed

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: tahnk you, got the result .but one issue in that ..for some of the jobname ..i have it ike long jobname with spaces, in that case the values it taking is wrong.could u pls help me in that situation.I will edit the question to include that condition also

Comment: Better opening a new question, as the answer would be quite different. You can link to the old question for context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70707779/text-processing-using-linux , added a new question. could u pls check it  @choroba

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but it's a start:

```
grep -i "elapse" test.txt | awk -F " " '{print $7 " " $5 " " $14}'
```