# Text processing using linux

Tags: bash

I have a text file like below.

```
0112 00000 34 JOB RECOVERY status poll (ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001) ACCEPTED, OWNER
0112 00000 35 JOB RECOVERY status poll (ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001)STARTED , APPL TYPE
0112 00000 36 JOB PROCESS Kafka(ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) ACCEPTED , OWNER
0112 00001 37 JOB PROCESS Kafka (ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) STARTED, APPL_TYPE
0112 00001 38 JOB RECOVERY  status poll(ORDERID 2N000, RUNNO 0001) ENDED OK ,ELAPSED - 0.02 SEC
0112 00003 39 JOB PROCESS (ORDERID 2N001, RUNNO 0001) ENDED OK, ELAPSED - 2.28 SEC
```

I need to get elapsed - value for each orderid for each job , I need like if orderid is 2N000, then the elapsed I should get-0.02 sec. like this for each orderid I need to get from the file using shell script.

I need the output like

```
orderid    jobname           ELAPSED
2N000      RECOVERY status   0.02
2NOO1      PROCESS  Kafka   2.28
```

If there is space in jobname or elapsed or orderid  , that also has to be evaluated .
Please find the parent version of the question:
[Parse a text file using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694374/parse-a-text-file-using-shell-script/70694737?noredirect=1#comment124998596_70694737).

Important note: `sed` is not available.

Comment: Do you have `perl` installed?

Comment: Why is `RECOVERY status` the job name and not `RECOVERY status poll`?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, we need RECOVERY status poll

Comment: no i dont have perl , i need to do it using linux shell

Comment: But `awk` is OK? awk is not linux shell, either.

Comment: awk is fine, with awk is there any way

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: bash  is the one i use

Comment: Is it correct that the last line doesn't contain "Kafka"?

Comment: last line with same orderid contains kafka also , i forgot to include it

Comment: Please fix it in the question.

Comment: The chances that you have Bash and AWK, but not Perl, are very **very** small....

Answer (score 2):

Bash solution:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -eu

while read line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ JOB' '([^\)]+)'('ORDERID' '([^,]+).*ELAPSED' '-' '([0-9.]+) ]] ; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:3}"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

It uses bash regex matching to extract the details from the lines that contain "ELAPSED".

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion assumes there is only a single whitespace whereas your example text have two whitespaces. And the job have mostly the same number of words and status is "ENDED OK". I have used `foreach` from zsh but this can be changed since looping, grepping and cutting are the primary tools.

The input file is called process.txt in this example.

```
foreach C (`grep "(ORDERID " process.txt|grep " ENDED OK"|cut -d "(" -f 2|cut -d "," -f 1|cut -d " " -f 2`)
  line=`grep $C process.txt|grep " ENDED OK"`
  job_name=`echo $line|cut -d " " -f 5`
  elapsed=`echo $line|cut -d "-" -f 2|cut -d " " -f 2`
  echo "$C $job_name $elapsed"
end
```

Output:

```
2N000 RECOVERY 0.02
2N001 PROCESS 2.28
```

Comment: what if i have something like Recovery status poll as jobname?

Comment: I was a bit imprecise. Jobname can be anything.

Comment: yeah..if there is single space or double space between words of jobname ?

Comment: and i cant remove the space between jobname , since at last i need to load all these to table, i need the jobname exact as what it is

Comment: If there are uknown number of whitespace the cut-command that use space (" ") as delimiter won't work as intended. So the output must be formatted to use only a single whitespace.